# Varying argument values and number -- is this legal C++?

Tags: c++, string, stl, iterator, tokenize

I'm trying to declare the following two functions to put back together a tokenized string (broken up into a vector or other iterator-compatible data structure):

```
std::string ComposeTokens(std::vector<std::string> Tokens);
std::string ComposeTokens(std::iterator first, std::iterator last);
```

In the implementation file (not provided here -- it's fairly obvious), Visual Studio's IntelliSense isn't recognizing either implementation as valid, saying that both conflict with both declarations. Compiling produces a message that iterators must have a template.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to, here? Would it work to declare iterator< string >, do I need pointers, etc.? And has the STL or Boost or some other library already done this?

Comment: "Compiling produces a message that iterators must have a template." Exactly. `std::iterator` isn't a fully-specified type -- what does it iterate over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v{"put", "me", "together"};

    std::cout << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this since it offers a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do -- although I mean no disrespect to the other answers, all of which have been helpful and informative (and which I've voted up).

Answer (score 4):

std::iterator is a base class template which at least needs a category and a class type defined.

You don't generally define iterators this way - you define it using templates:

```
template <typename Iterator>
std::string ComposeTokens(Iterator first, Iterator last);
```

Also, you probably want to be passing your vector by reference:

```
std::string ComposeTokens(std::vector<std::string>& Tokens);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make your iterator function a template:

```
template <class Iterator>
std::string ComposeTokens(Iterator first, Iterator last);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly ok to overload methods. VS is not complaining about that.

I think it's complaining because you're not using iterators correctly.
When you ask a question about a compiler error it's best to post the actual error, you'll get better answers.

As for iterators, they are templated and `std::iterator` is incomplete, hence the error. If your iterators are supposed to come from a vector then use `std::vector<std::string>::iterator` instead.

Comment: For the record: the particular error was: `error C2955: 'std::iterator' : use of class template requires template argument list` -- which should've made it fairly obvious to me what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) is not what you think it is.

The easiest solution would be:

```
template <typename Iter>
std::string ComposeTokens(Iter first, Iter last);
```